# Google Analytics configuration file can't be created

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics to my iOS app, and there seems to have been some changes in the SDK. The tutorial at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ says that I have to create a configuration file, but when I click on the "Get a configuration file" link I'm directed to a page that just shows a loading spinner (with some errors printed to the browser console).

I don't have time to wait for Google to fix their service, so I'm wondering if it's possible to create the file manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that if you look at the error in the browser console and go to the URL it can't load, you can sign in and it works. And thereafter, the original link works too.

Comment: This worked for me. I also happened to notice that when I created a new Property in the GA Admin panel, the configuration file generator page would load properly.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me as well. But it's crazy people have to experience this problem on Google's website

Comment: Yeah... and then the Google VP of Product Management wonders why only 21% of the apps use Analytics... I bet a lot of app devs gave up the use of Analytics due to this really anoying problem, just like I was about to!

Answer (score 4):

As crazy as it sounds, I resolved this error by using Internet Explorer to load the site.

Answer (score 0):

user102008's answer worked for me. I also noticed that if you create a new Property in the GA Admin panel, the configuration file generator page will load properly.